# Android studio LWP

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gif, mp4

I'm new developer (NOOB) and right now I'm making a simple live wallpaper and its finished however I'd like to use mp4 instead of gif, Is that even possible?
and how can I change canvas.scale so that it fits any screen automatically? 
here's my java code:

package com.mahdiharaji.watchdogsLWP;

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.io.IOException;


public class GIFWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public WallpaperService.Engine onCreateEngine() {
        try {
            Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("wd.gif"));
            return new GIFWallpaperEngine(movie);
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("GIF","Could not load asset");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class GIFWallpaperEngine extends WallpaperService.Engine {
        private final int frameduration = 20;

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Movie movie;
        private boolean visible;
        private Handler handler;

        public GIFWallpaperEngine(Movie movie){
            this.movie= movie;
            handler= new Handler();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            this.holder= surfaceHolder;
        }

        private Runnable drawGIF = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw();
            };
        };

        private void draw(){
            if(visible){
                Canvas canvas= holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.save();
            //adjust size and position
            canvas.scale(4f,4f);
            movie.draw(canvas,-100, 0);
            canvas.restore();
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            movie.setTime((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % movie.duration()));

            handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
            handler.postDelayed(drawGIF,frameduration);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visible= visible;
            if(visible){
                handler.post(drawGIF);
            } else {handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);}
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
        }
    }
}
```

If possible I'd want it to be simple
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks